# Get child layers from a layer group

Tags: geoserver, layers, grouping

I'm using a geoserver and openlayers3 with html. I cannot find the way to obtain the child layers from a layer group. I have a layer group, and I show it in html perfectly, but what I want is to be able to access their children layer, in order to print a checkbox for each one to be able to choose if I want to hide or show each one. I don't know if it's possible, and if so, if I have to make a call using the geoserver to get the layers and then make the call to print them, or it is some method inside openlayer.

The code to print the layer group:

```
new ol.layer.Group({
    title: 'layer1_group',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'layer1_group',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://testestest:8080/geoserver/geo.test/wms?service=WMS',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'layer_group_3layers'},
          serverType: 'geoserver',
          crossOrigin: null
        })
      })
    ]
  })
```

layer1_group: contains 3 sub layers. Those three are what I want to print separately.

So now I print only the layer group with the children all together, as the shown image: [image]

And what I want is to print the children separate:

[image]

Comment: Please share some code with us, and possibly a screenshot.

Comment: Doesn't the GetCapabilities response contain all information that you need?

Comment: @user30184 this bring all info, and I only want the related to the layergroup. Is there a way to filter to only get what I really want?

Comment: Geoserver documentation tells me that there are [5 modes for layer groups](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#layer-group-modes). Are you sure that your layer group is not an _opaque container_ meaning that it wouldn't list it's layers?

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone the layer group is as container-tree so the child are accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

If you want to get the children layers from a layer group then you have to make a call to the api, like that:

http://your_server/geoserver/your_schema/your_LAYER_GROUP/wms?request=GetCapabilities

So you have to fill in the url with your data, taking care where it puts "your_LAYER_GROUP" to enter your layer group. With this you will have an xml containing a node named as `<Layer>` and inside it, it will appear N nodes deppending on the number of sub layers that the parent has.

Then to print it dinamically from an html site, using javascript is easy:

```
var layerNew = new ol.layer.Tile({
        title: 'new ',
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://your_server/geoserver/your_schema/wms?service=WMS',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'THE_LAYER_NAME_THAT_APPEARS_IN_THE_XML'},
          serverType: 'geoserver',
          crossOrigin: null
        }) });

map.addLayer(layerNew)
```